# Importing exported sqlite db to mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.33` and I have exported a database with Db Browser for SQLite:

[image]

Now I am trying to import the exported `mysql -u root my_database  < exportFile.sqlite.sql`  to my mysql server.

However, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 1
```

My sql file is around 500 Mb large. The first 100 lines of my sql file are the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_statistics`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_statistics` (
    `virt_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `virt_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `last_verified` TIMESTAMP,
    `row_count` INTEGER,
    `extent_min_x`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_min_y`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_max_x`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_max_y`  DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vrtgc_statistics` FOREIGN KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) REFERENCES `virts_geometry_columns`(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vrtgc_statistics` PRIMARY KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_field_infos`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_field_infos` (
    `virt_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `virt_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ordinal`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `column_name`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `null_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `integer_values`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `double_values` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `text_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `blob_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `max_size`  INTEGER,
    `integer_min`   INTEGER,
    `integer_max`   INTEGER,
    `double_min`    DOUBLE,
    `double_max`    DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vrtgcfld_infos` FOREIGN KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) REFERENCES `virts_geometry_columns`(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vrtgcfld_infos` PRIMARY KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`,`ordinal`,`column_name`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_auth`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns_auth` (
    `virt_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `virt_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hidden`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `ck_vrtgc_hidden` CHECK(hiddenIN(0,1)),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vrtgc_auth` FOREIGN KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) REFERENCES `virts_geometry_columns`(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vrtgc_auth` PRIMARY KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virts_geometry_columns` (
    `virt_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `virt_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `geometry_type` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `coord_dimension`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `srid`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_geom_cols_virts` PRIMARY KEY(`virt_name`,`virt_geometry`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vgc_srid` FOREIGN KEY(`srid`) REFERENCES `spatial_ref_sys`(`srid`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_statistics`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_statistics` (
    `view_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `view_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `last_verified` TIMESTAMP,
    `row_count` INTEGER,
    `extent_min_x`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_min_y`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_max_x`  DOUBLE,
    `extent_max_y`  DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vwgc_statistics` FOREIGN KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) REFERENCES `views_geometry_columns`(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vwgc_statistics` PRIMARY KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_field_infos`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_field_infos` (
    `view_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `view_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `ordinal`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `column_name`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `null_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `integer_values`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `double_values` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `text_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `blob_values`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `max_size`  INTEGER,
    `integer_min`   INTEGER,
    `integer_max`   INTEGER,
    `double_min`    DOUBLE,
    `double_max`    DOUBLE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vwgcfld_infos` FOREIGN KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) REFERENCES `views_geometry_columns`(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vwgcfld_infos` PRIMARY KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`,`ordinal`,`column_name`)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_auth`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `views_geometry_columns_auth` (
    `view_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `view_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hidden`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_vwgc_auth` FOREIGN KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) REFERENCES `views_geometry_columns`(`view_name`,`view_geometry`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `pk_vwgc_auth` PRIMARY KEY(`view_name`,`view_geometry`),
    CONSTRAINT `ck_vwgc_hidden` CHECK(hiddenIN(0,1))
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `views_geometry_columns`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `views_geometry_columns` (
    `view_name` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `view_geometry` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `view_rowid`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `f_table_name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `f_geometry_column` TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Any suggestions why I get the above error?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Use `START TRANSACTION;` instead, but this is the least of your problems. There are other issues like changing all TEXT data types to VARCHAR with a specified length and also and problematic foreign key constraints.

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are two different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. You cannot expect to simply dump a database schema from one and be able to restore it to the other.

Comment: You're also going to have a problem creating foreign keys that reference tables you haven't declared yet. In MySQL, the tables must be created in a specific order, or else you create all the tables without declaring foreign key constraints, and then add the foreign keys afterwards using ALTER TABLE.

Comment: I also notice none of your tables have a PRIMARY KEY constraint. This isn't an error, but it's a bad practice on MySQL or in fact any relational database. All tables should have a PRIMARY KEY constraint, otherwise it's impossible to query a specific row.